# else statement not displaying data

Tags: php

i have some code to check for duplicates in a db before submitting the data, but the statement i have does not work. if a duplicate is found a message is returned to the form. however, it is not working and i am sure it has to do with my else statements near the bottom of the file being incorrect. assume all connections are working. where is the error? many thanks

```
<?php
$array = split('[,]', $_POST['fileno']);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    foreach ($array as $fileno) {
        if ($fileno == '' && $box == '')
            {
                echo '<div style="background-color:#ffa; padding:2px; color:#ff0000;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal">' . 'You must incude a box and a file' . '</div>';

            }
        elseif ($fileno == '')
            {

                echo '<div style="background-color:#ffa; padding:2px; color:#ff0000;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal">' . 'You must enter a file reference' . '</div>';
            }
        elseif ($box == '')
            {
                //echo error;
                echo '<div style="background-color:#ffa; padding:2px; color:#ff0000;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal">' . 'You must enter a box' . '</div>';
            }
        else
            {
                $sql = "SELECT custref FROM files WHERE custref = '$fileno' ";
                $result = runSQL($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
                    echo '<div style="background-color:#ffa; padding:2px; color:#ff0000;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal">' . $fileno . '  is already in the database. No duplicates' . '</div>';

                }
                $sql = "SELECT custref FROM boxes WHERE custref = '$box' ";
                $result = runSQL($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
                    echo '<div style="background-color:#ffa; padding:2px; color:#ff0000;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal">' . $box . '  is already in the database. No duplicates' . '</div>';
                }

                else
                    {
                        //insert into db;
                        echo '<div style="background-color:#ffa; padding:2px; color:#33CC33;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal">' . $fileno . "Box: " . $box . $authorised . 'Successfull' . '</div>';
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO `files` (customer, authorisation, boxstatus, boxref, custref, filestatus) VALUES ('$customer', '$authorised', '$boxstatus', '$box', '$fileno', $filestatus)";
                        $result = runSQL($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                        //echo 'This record is valid';
                        //header("Location: http://localhost/sample/admin/files/index.php");
                        //exit();
                    }
            }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I assumed "not working" means you're NOT seeing is a unique entry being written to the database? Because it's not clear what you're actually asking.

Comment: 1) use empty() to chek if a varriable is empty 
2) do you get any errors ? no ? turn display_errors on

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether it is coming in this section:-

```
// Some logic
if (...) {
    // some more logic
}
...
elseif ($box == '') {
    //echo error;
    echo '<div style="background-color:#ffa; padding:2px; color:#ff0000;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal">' . 'You must enter a box' . '</div>';
}
else {
    echo 'check it here please';
    // some more logic
}
...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: elseif ($box == '')
            {
                //echo error;
                echo '<div style="background-color:#ffa; padding:2px; color:#ff0000;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal">' . 'You must enter a box' . '</div>';
            }

Comment: frank ->if a duplicate is found a message is returned to the form

Answer (score 0):

Put some echos to check the values:

```
foreach ($array as $fileno) {
    echo "fileno='$fileno' , box='$box'<br>";
  ......
```

then in each block of if/elseif

```
echo "i'm running line : ",__LINE__,"<br>";
```

What do you obtain ?

Comment: Could you sho us, by editing your question, what error message you've got and what the echoes display ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using exit();/die(); in your echoed errors(not the best way of error handling! - [try exceptions out](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)) instead of encapsulating dependent code in an else. I suspect this may fix your issue, as you're only checking to add the row against one of your error statements.

Comment: sorry. i do not understand your answer.

Comment: Ok...without having a large block of code here: Your last else statement is only in response to the single if line before it that checks for a boxes duplicate. It doesn't involve the first files duplicate check at all. Which is why I was saying remove the else statement at the end completely and have those two if statements that echo duplicate error messages have die() or exit() inside them so the code below just isn't run instead of running it inside of an else statement. I'll edit my main post when I'm available again to show you code example of what I mean.